# Draw a horizontal line in latex

Tags: rules

[image: Horizontal line picture]

How can I draw this horizontal line like this picture in Latex? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean `\hrule`? That should be what you're looking for

Comment: As opposed to \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt} which is treated like wide character rather than a tiny paragraph.

Comment: If by chance this rule is supposed to be above a code listing as in the screenshot, then you could also see whether the environment you use for the code has the possibility to add it. Both `minted` and `listings` have this feature, for example. (@Moriambar Why don't you just add an answer instead of voting to close?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. good idea

Comment: Note also that `\hrulefill` will extend the line to the right margin of the current scope, so that you can avoid specifying a length.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Comment: @ViktorStein There is no way to coerce someone into accepting any answer. They can just ask and never come back. This does not makes any answer less valid. Just lets the question open, in the system's vision.

Answer (score 167):

I see two choices, one using `\rule` (as suggested by @John Kormylo) and one using `\hrule`. I'll describe them both and give an example at the end

---

The `\rule` command constructs a box, which is treated like a character and has the following syntax `\rule[h]{w}{t}` where `h` `w` and `t` are *lengths* and represent respectively:

- the height above the baseline to which raise the box (defaults at 0)
- the width of the box
- the thickness of the rule

In your case

```
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
```

should do the trick.

---

The `\hrule` command is a TeX primitive and is a bit more complicated to use because it suppresses the interline spacing. Its full syntax is as follows:

```
\hrule height h depth d width w \relax
```

where `h`, `d` and `w` should be substituted with the appropriate lengths (height is the thickness of the rule). Any order of `height` `depth` and `width` are supported, and any or all of them can be left out, which will make TeX use the following defaults:

- `height` will be `0.4 pt`
- `depth` will be `0pt`
- `width` will make the rule extend to the boundary of the outer box.

Usually `hrule` is to be used between paragraphs, otherwise it will start or stop a paragraph. The `\relax` is not always needed, but it prevents the misinterpretation of following words and numbers when there is ambiguity

**Note** sometimes it's useful to use `\vspace` before or after the `\hrule` to space it from the previous and next paragraphs. In this case I don't know the specifics of the problem to determine the proper spacing of the rule suitable for you.

---

Example (the `\vspace`s are random)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{5pt}
\hrule
\vspace{6pt}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had gotten stuck making the footnoterule to the right:

Comment: +1 for using `\rule` for custom line thickness

Comment: This answer is wrong or outdated. As my provided answer proves, `\hrule` is not "a bit more complicated to use". In fact, it does not requires any argument, so it is the more simple to use that any command can get.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah No, your answer is extremely incomplete, (not to mention simply giving a link) and this answer is entirely correct. `\hrule` is a TeX primitive, and so not actually a LaTeX command, and so its behaviour isn't as you might expect since it removes the interline spacing.  And it does take the arguments shown in the answer. But, as the example code here shows, it *can* be used without any arguments, as well since the example here is almost identical to the one in your link.